# Matching Angles between Edges

Tags: python, math, vector

I'm scripting in python for starters.
Making this example simple, I have one edge, with uv Coordinates of ([0,0],[1,1]), so its a 45 degree angle.  I have another edge that is ([0,0],[0,1]) so its angle is 0/360 degrees.  My goal is to compare the angles of those two edges in order to get the difference so I can modify the angle of the second edge to match the angle of the first edge.  Is there a way to do this via vector math?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you sure that the first lists (points) in those two tuples (edges) are the same? Are you asking to calculate the angles between those two vectors? If both those are yes, use the Law of Cosines or the dot product (which are basically the same). You could also use the atan2() function, but that is more complicated.

Comment: The points are UV Coordinates, not XYZ coordinates, the edges are a pair of these coords.

Comment: I do have a code example of dot product for comparing vectors between three points to see if they're the same, I'm not sure how to get the difference in angle however.

Comment: The dot product (which you can code easily) will give you the cosine of the angle between the vectors. The function `atan2()` (which I suppose Python provides, I don't know Python) will give you the angles of the two functions so that you can then subtract them. Which approach do you like?

Comment: @Beta: Python has `atan2` in the math unit. The complications with that are that the subtraction of the two direction angles can give negative or reflex angles, and normalizing the result is a slight nuisance. Also, the zero vector has no direction.

Comment: @Beta, I'm not familiar with atan2() so an example of it would be nice, but dot product works best as I already have some code examples of it?

Comment: You can find examples of `atan2()` easily, and you'll find the function very simple if you understand the idea of arctangent. Likewise the dot product of two vectors is equal to the magnitude of the first, times the magnitude of the second, times the cosine of the angle between them; so you can get the angle if you can calculate the magnitudes and you have `acos()`. Whether you write the code yourself or someone writes it for you, **you will have great difficulty with it if you don't master the underlying mathematics.**

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to reconstruct and thus constructively remember is IMO the complex picture. To compute the angle from `a=a.x+i*a.y` to `b=b.x+i*b.y` rotate `b` back by multiplying with the conjugate of `a` to get an angle from the zero angle resp. the positive real axis,

```
arg((a.x-i*a.y)*(b.x+i*b.y))

=arg((a.x*b.x+a.y*b.y)+i*(a.x*b.y-a.y*b.x))

=atan2( a.x*b.y-a.y*b.x , a.x*b.x+a.y*b.y )
```

Note that screen coordinates use the opposite orientation to the Cartesian/complex plane, thus change use a sign switch as from `atan2(y,x)` to `atan2(-y,x)` to get an angle in the usual direction.

---

To produce a vector `b` rotated angle (in radians) `w` from `a`, multiply by `cos(w)+i*sin(w)` to obtain

```
b.x = cos(w)*a.x - sin(w)*a.y
b.y = cos(w)*a.y + sin(w)*a.x
```

You will have to rescale to get a specified length of `b`.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you LutzL... are a and b, 45 and 0 respectively?

Comment: No. Using numbers from your question, it could be `a=(a.x,a.y)=(1,1)` and `b=(1,0)`. In general, these vectors are the differences to the rotation center, which was (probably) `(0,0)` in your question.